# Does Cold Damage Slow Enemy Movement Speed Only?

Tags: diablo-iii

When dealing cold damage to an enemy, what all does it slow down?  I know it obviously slows down an enemies movement speed, but does it affect casting time?  Or does it slow down their attacks also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cold damage applies a snare effect to the enemy.  This effect slows them generally, so yes, it slows their attacks, casting and so forth.

I have no citation for this other than my extensive use of cold weapons and caltrops over the last 60 levels.

Comment: I *thought* so also I just didn't know if there was anything citation wise or proof wise to go with it.

Comment: Can someone provide a value for the slow?  I am not sure if it is out there, but if you had cold damage on a weapon, how much does it slow them?