# What exactly is Chilled in Diablo 3? Does cold damage chilled 100%?

Tags: diablo-iii

Cold damaged always slow enemies even if done by your scoundrel.

Does that means scoundrel's attack, with Buriza, will have 100% chill rate? Buriza is a cold damage weapon.

Will that synchronize with wizard talent that increase damage against frozen or chilled enemies?

A popular build nowaday is to buy Buriza for scoundrel. Many said that they want those with high freeze rate to synchronize with cold blood.

However, if Buriza will chill 100% then it's not much of an issue?

Yes I know that cold damage slow enemies. However, does it "chill" the enemies? Will it proc cold blood? That is the essence of the question.

Comment: Covered in this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63625/what-are-all-the-status-effects-and-what-do-they-mean

Comment: Not covered. I asked whether cold weapon damage chill. I don't know.

Comment: That's not what your title says.

Comment: Isn't this exactly like your [other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78469/does-blizzard-actually-slow-enemies-down-and-by-how-much)?  And if you're really asking if cold weapons apply a chill effect, you have the question @JamesJiao linked, and [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76441/does-cold-damage-slow-enemy-movement-speed-only).

Comment: Slowed and chilled are 2 possibly different things. If cold weapons apply 100% chill effect, it would have show up that way in auction house.

Comment: I am not even sure that blizzard give chill effect with 100% rate. But yea it's related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All damage from cold sources apply a chill effect.  The reason why you would want a buriza on a scoundrel is not for the freeze effect (which is quite handy), but because it can potentially pierce to hit multiple targets in a pack.

This will definately proc cold blooded, as will any cold damage source.  Just keep in mind that the duration of the chill may be different on uniques as its considered a source of CC.

Comment: source? What's your source

Comment: @JimThio my source: I have a 400k dps wizard that I use to solo the game with? :P

Comment: I have 330k wizard.